# Exploring results of L´evy Continuity Theorem (relating moment generating functions and nth moments)

Tags: probability, integration, functions, moment-generating-functions, levy-processes

[Updated - Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgkIu.png)

[Link to Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k29Ul.png)

I'm having trouble with the second part. My proof of the first part simply said that only Mx(t) = My(t) implies X and Y have the same CDF. E(X^n) = E(Y^n) does not always imply X and Y have the same CDF, as there are cases where the nth moments are equal (power series converge to same number) but the actual RVs X and Y have different distributions. I have no idea how to even approach the second part. It is very intimidating.

Comment: What is the book? And what is its statement of Levy's continuity theorem (weak form)?

Comment: I added the exact statement of Levy's continuity theorem we are given.

Answer (score 1):

They give a hint!

Write
$$E(X_a^n) = \int_0^\infty x^n\frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\log(x)^2/2}(1+a\sin(2\pi\log(x)))dx$$

now transform to $s = \log(x)-n$ so that $ds = dx/x$ and $x = e^{n+s}$ and you get
$$\begin{align}E(X_a^n) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{n(n+s)}e^{-(n+s)^2/2}(1+a\sin(2\pi(n+s)))ds \\ &= \frac{e^{n^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2/2}(1+a\sin(2\pi s))ds\end{align}$$
where in the second line we cleaned up what was in the exponential and used that $\sin(2\pi n + x) = \sin(x)$. Notice the term proportional to $s$ canceled out. Do you see why the final answer won't depend on $a$?

Also, I think they're looking for something different for part 1. Part 2 is *showing* that just because two distributions have all the same moments doesn't mean they're equal. All you do in your answer is state this. They want a reason that this doesn't violate the assumptions of the Levy continuity theorem. I don't know the statement of the theorem (never heard of a 'weak form' anyway), so I don't know for sure, but I expect the reason you might think it does superficially is that if the moments are all the same, then since the moment-generating function is a power series whose coefficients are the moments, then all the moments being the same should mean the moment-generating function is the same. Where's the hole in that argument?

Comment: Thanks, this helps alot. I see that no matter what n is, since n is an integer, it wont affect the sin term. I also see better how you integrated the hint into the question. I still don't understand how exactly the answer won't depend on a though. I know the question is begging you to find that a doesn't matter so that when you plug a different b, the nth moments are still the same despite the moments generating functions being different. I do agree that part 1 is looking for a different answer. I think I need a counterexample to prove my statement, but I think part (ii) serves as the counter.

Comment: @Adam The term with $a$ in it integrates to zero. Regarding part 1, yes, part 2 is a counterexample. But do you see why in this example you can't simply say $M_{X_a}(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{E(X_a^n)}{n!}t^n$ so that $M_{X_a}(t) = M_{X_b}(t)$?